# how invoke search for spinner in Android?

Tags: android, search, android-spinner

in may application, i have a spinner widget that contains huge amount of data.
it is hard for user to find his item between them, so i decided to insert search capability for content of spinner.the idea is If the user taps the quick search button he should be provided with a text field to enter a letter and then the spinner list jumps to the fist word it finds with the letter supplied. 
is there any solution to that?
thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume, full Spinner data is list.

Initialize

`listCurrent=list.clone();`

set ArrayAdapter on spinner by

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1, listCurrent);
```

override onTouch event, open dialog containing edit text say editText and a button on tap, else select item, in dialog button click, get String from editText and filter results and reset adapter by invoking:

```
listCurrent= filter(list, text);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do things you want is

Have an Button which contain the Text of Selection. 
When the Button is clicked Open the Dialog or Activity(startActivityForResult) containing the ListView with EditText.

update the listview with the Searched content in EditText.

When user click on an Item in the ListView. finish the Activity with result.

and update the Text in Button from onActivityResult.

Answer (score -1):

You can use auto-compilation...

Comment: what is auto-compilation?